# sqlactivity for redshift copy in amazon datapipeline does not pick wild card characters for filenames

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-data-pipeline

I am using the sqlActivity in amazon data pipeline to copy data to my redshift table.
The script runs fine if I specify one fileName like part-00000.gz but when i specify the wildcard *.gz to pick all files in the directory I get the error where the wildcard is actually considered to be the filename and so it complains that the filename Output/Prod/Bens_Analytics/2015/02/10/IP_To_FileName/*.gz does not exist

begin transaction;
  create temp table ip_to_filename_staging_table (like   bens_analytics_ip_to_filename);

copy ip_to_filename_staging_table from 's3://er-hadoop/Output/Prod/Bens_Analytics/2015/02/10/IP_To_FileName/*.gz'
     credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<>;aws_secret_access_key=<>'
     gzip delimiter '\t' COMPUPDATE OFF STATUPDATE OFF;

delete from ip_to_filename_staging_table using bens_analytics_ip_to_filename
    where (ip_to_filename_staging_table.day = bens_analytics_ip_to_filename.day and ip_to_filename_staging_table.ip = bens_analytics_ip_to_filename.ip
    and ip_to_filename_staging_table.filename = bens_analytics_ip_to_filename.filename);

insert into bens_analytics_ip_to_filename select * from ip_to_filename_staging_table;

drop table ip_to_filename_staging_table;
  end transaction;

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out
when i used a path like 's3://er-hadoop/Output/Prod/Bens_Analytics/2015/02/10/IP_To_FileName/part'  it picked all the part-xxxxx.gz files